What is SYSTEM$BIND in Snowflake
I see in my query history
​​CREATE TEMPORARY STAGE IF NOT EXISTS SYSTEM$BIND file_format=( type=csv field_optionally_enclosed_by='"')
put file:///tmp/placeholder '@SYSTEM$BIND/11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555' overwrite=true​
INSERT INTO xxx (col1, col2) VALUES (?,?)

But I can't find a direct definition of SYSTEM$BIND in https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-system (which makes sense since it's not a function) or anywhere else in the "regular" documentation.
​And from the Using the JDBC Driver > Batch inserts I understand that it's the snowflake driver itself  that creates a temporary stage called SYSTEM$BIND while doing batch inserts, and the INSERT INTO afterward must somehow get the data from that internal stage SYSTEM$BIND.
But I don't see any reference to SYSTEM$BIND itself in the INSERT INTO in the query history so how does it actually work?

I have inspected the source for the java jdbc snowflake driver and the snowflake-connector-python and I see that the JDBC driver uses SYSTEM$BIND as stage name and python uses SYSTEMBIND instead as stage name.
There is no special meaning associated with SYSTEM$BIND or SYSTEMBIND it's just a unique name that they decided.
The driver will ultimately send a POST request to /queries/v1/query-request and pass the name of the stage as bindStage in the body. Source here and here)
I don't think the API that the drivers (jdbc and python)  use is documented and seems to be fundamentally different from the SQL REST API
You can tell the internal stage is used in the INSERT INTO by looking at the query profile, you will see an External Scan > INTERNAL_STAGE node with attributes Stage type = INTERNAL_STAGE and Stage Name = DATABASENAME.SCHEMANAME.SYSTEM$BIND
